# Keras/Tensorflow/h5py - KeyError: "Can't open attribute (Can't locate attribute: 'nb_layers')"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, h5py

I have the following code snippet:

```
def save_bottleneck_features():
    """builds the pretrained vgg16 model and runs it on our training and validation datasets"""
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    # match the vgg16 architecture so we can load the pretrained weights into this model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf", input_shape=(1022, 767, 3)))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(3, img_width, img_height)))

    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_1'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_2'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_1'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_2'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_1'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_2'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_3'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_1'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_2'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_3'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_1'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_2'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_3'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    # load VGG16 weights
    f = h5py.File(weights_path)

    for k in range(f.attrs['nb_layers']):
        if k >= len(model.layers):
            break
        g = f['layer_{}'.format(k)]
        weights = [g['param_{}'.format(p)] for p in range(g.attrs['nb_params'])]
        model.layers[k].set_weights(weights)

    f.close()
    print('Model loaded.')

    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_data_dir,
            target_size=(img_width, img_height),
            batch_size=32,
            class_mode=None,
            shuffle=False)
    bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(generator, nb_train_samples)
    np.save(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'wb'), bottleneck_features_train)

    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
            validation_data_dir,
            target_size=(img_width, img_height),
            batch_size=32,
            class_mode=None,
            shuffle=False)
    bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(generator, nb_validation_samples)
    np.save(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy', 'wb'), bottleneck_features_validation)
```

I call the `save_bottleneck_features()` function, but the file `bottleneck_features_validation.npy` seems not to be created, as I'm getting the error below, or is it something to do with the `h5` file?

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 362, in <module>
    train_top_model()
  File "train.py", line 178, in train_top_model
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
NameError: name 'train_data' is not defined

C:\Users\Abder-Rahman\Desktop\Testing\skin lesion detection\skin_lesion_classification\unaltered_classification>python train.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
train.py:99: UserWarning: Update your `MaxPooling2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `MaxPooling2D(data_format="channels_last", pool_size=(2, 2), input_shape=(1022, 767...)`
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf", input_shape=(1022, 767, 3)))
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
train.py:102: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(64, (3, 3), name="conv1_1", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_1'))
train.py:104: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(64, (3, 3), name="conv1_2", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_2'))
train.py:108: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(128, (3, 3), name="conv2_1", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_1'))
train.py:110: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(128, (3, 3), name="conv2_2", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_2'))
train.py:114: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(256, (3, 3), name="conv3_1", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_1'))
train.py:116: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(256, (3, 3), name="conv3_2", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_2'))
train.py:118: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(256, (3, 3), name="conv3_3", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_3'))
train.py:122: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(512, (3, 3), name="conv4_1", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_1'))
train.py:124: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(512, (3, 3), name="conv4_2", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_2'))
train.py:126: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(512, (3, 3), name="conv4_3", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_3'))
train.py:130: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(512, (3, 3), name="conv5_1", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_1'))
train.py:132: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(512, (3, 3), name="conv5_2", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_2'))
train.py:134: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(512, (3, 3), name="conv5_3", activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_3'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 361, in <module>
    save_bottleneck_features()
  File "train.py", line 140, in save_bottleneck_features
    for k in range(f.attrs['nb_layers']):
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (D:\Build\h5py\h5py-2.7.0\h5py\_objects.c:2853)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (D:\Build\h5py\h5py-2.7.0\h5py\_objects.c:2811)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\attrs.py", line 58, in __getitem__
    attr = h5a.open(self._id, self._e(name))
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (D:\Build\h5py\h5py-2.7.0\h5py\_objects.c:2853)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (D:\Build\h5py\h5py-2.7.0\h5py\_objects.c:2811)
  File "h5py\h5a.pyx", line 77, in h5py.h5a.open (D:\Build\h5py\h5py-2.7.0\h5py\h5a.c:2350)
KeyError: "Can't open attribute (Can't locate attribute: 'nb_layers')"
```

**EDIT 1**

You can kindly download the full script from, here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/00ha6y3oqxlrxs7/program.py?dl=1

Thanks.

Comment: You need to do things : First, update both keras and tensorflow. Second, you need to check that before you call `top_model()` whether train_data is loaded or not and if yes, is it in the correct format ?

Comment: @Nain Thanks for your kind reply. I made sure that Keras and Tensorflow are updated. Sorry, I didn't get your second point. I have added the full script in **EDIT 1** in the question.

Comment: Your code is giving an error on this line `train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'rb'))`. So, open a terminal, fire python and check whether this file is present in the same directory and is readable or not

Comment: @Nain Yes, this file doesn't exist. Should it be generated or it has to be available already?

Comment: yes. You should run your bottleneck features function first on your data to generate this file and then you should pass this to the top_model function